# How to add a suffix to a sequence of variables in R?

Tags: r, dplyr

My dataset has over 6k variables and I need to add a suffix to a sequence of variables, but not all of them. I'm trying:

```
data <- data %>%
  rename_at(AGRA_A00_A09:AGRII_U80_U89, ~paste0(., "_cor"))
```

But I get the following error:

```
Error: object 'AGRA_A00_A09' not found
```

I've tried putting quote marks on the variables names and using across, but it still doesn't work. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Close, use `rename_with`:

```r
mtcars %>%
  rename_with(disp:drat, .fn = ~ paste0(., "_cor")) %>%
  head()
#                    mpg cyl disp_cor hp_cor drat_cor    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
# Mazda RX4         21.0   6      160    110     3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4
# Mazda RX4 Wag     21.0   6      160    110     3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4
# Datsun 710        22.8   4      108     93     3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1
# Hornet 4 Drive    21.4   6      258    110     3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1
# Hornet Sportabout 18.7   8      360    175     3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2
# Valiant           18.1   6      225    105     2.76 3.460 20.22  1  0    3    1
```